# Filter extended properties by contact id

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, extended-properties

With this code I get the extended properties for contacts with a specific display name:

```cs
foreach(Contact c in contacts)
{
  // some code...
  view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, properties);
  filter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, c.DisplayName);
  items = service.FindItems(folderId, filter, view);
}
```

I want to filter not by the `DisplayName` but by the `Contact.Id`, but i can't find a way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I have done in the end, i did not find a better solution.
I get all contacts with the same name and iterate through them to find the correct contact.

```
        foreach (Item item in items.Items)
        {
            foreach (var ext in item.ExtendedProperties)
            {
                // check if the extended property is from this contact
                if (c.Id.ChangeKey == item.Id.ChangeKey)
                {
                    extendedProperties.Add(ext);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To search by [`Contact.Id`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.id%28v=exchg.80%29) use the [`ItemSchema.Id`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.itemschema.id%28v=exchg.80%29) like given below...

```cs
filter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ItemSchema.Id, c.Id);
```

Comment: I tried, but it throws an ArgumentException with the message "Validation failed. Parameter name: searchFilter"